# Spring Scheduler

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks

I go through spring Scheduler support documentation.

where I found:

```
ScheduledFuture schedule (Runnable task, Date startTime);
```

But in case of `@EnableScheduling` there is no Thread Implementation in various examples.

Why??
any one can explain
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @EnableScheduling you just enable the spring scheduler functionality.

To run a task you would annotate a public method with @Scheduled.
So you see that you dont need a runnable / thread for this as your annotabed method will be called using reflection.

```
@EnableScheduling
public class Tasks {

 @Scheduled(... options here)
 public void myTasks(){
     //doSomethingHere...
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks @NeoP5 If I add the XML Scema based Do i need Implement Runnable.

Comment: hi, no you dont need. see the snipped below:
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="beanA" method="methodA" fixeddelay="5000"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="10"/>

Comment: Yes Thanks...It bit Intersting May need some more documentation for clarity.

Comment: Yes, just look for the spring documentation and tutorials. they are very good.

Comment: my requirement is send an email every day at 12 o'clock from a new thread that can pool of data from db and send email.how to do in spring scheduler.

Comment: You can use the standard cron expression: @Schedule(cron=""0 0 12 * * *"")

Comment: Technically yes, but i would not recommend this or you might mess up threading as spring is already creating a thread. Actually i don´t know how this will act. Better move your logic to an other public void method and if needed call this method from within your Thread.start() method.

Answer (score 0):

our class must have at least these annotations :

package org.springframework.scheduling.annotation

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
```

you can set it with a fixedDelay

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
```

with initialDelay also:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000, initialDelay = 1000)
```

or with a fixedRate (when each execution of the task is independent)

```
 @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
```

you can also create it on runtime using

```
org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfigurer

public class SchedulerContextconfig implements SchedulingConfigurer
@Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar register) {

 register.addCronTask(Runnable task, String expression)

}
```